# particular custom font used is not working in android application

Tags: android, fonts

i am using DIEHL DECO font for my text view. the class file in my code is as below. the application is running without any errors but the font displayed is the default font. the font is not changed to the font file I am using.
I tried with another font file the code runs well but does not run well for this particular font. not understanding what the issue is. please help me.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
       }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
            super.setTypeface(TypeFaces.getTypeFace(getContext(),
                    "fonts/DIEHLD_.ttf"));
        } else if (style == Typeface.ITALIC) {
            super.setTypeface(TypeFaces.getTypeFace(getContext(),
                    "fonts/DIEHLD_.ttf"));
        } else {
            super.setTypeface(TypeFaces.getTypeFace(getContext(),
                    "fonts/DIEHLD_.ttf"));
        }
    }

}
```

this is the typefaces class

```
public class TypeFaces {
    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                            context.getAssets(), assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, typeFace);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TypeFaces", "Typeface not loaded.");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use assets/fonts/DIEHLD_.ttf, if you hae created fonts folder in assets folder.

Comment: This should be in comment

Comment: i have to try it yet. but this seems weird as it works well for other font files like chantelli antiqua. how its changing path name gonna help.  @maven what should be in comment.

Comment: If it still not work, change the .ttf file name from DIEHLD_.ttf to diehld.ttf.

Comment: i have tried both the solutions but its still not working. do think is it some problem with the font file.

Comment: yes, you should download ttf file from some where else and use.

Comment: i am getting error in log as Typeface not loaded, as i have thrown exception in Typeface class of my code.

Comment: Finally the issue is solved i guess the issue was with the font file only, and path should be "fonts/diehld.ttf". thank you for the help.

Comment: Perfect way to do it is to create 'fonts' folder in assets folder and add .ttf file in fonts folder, which means path will be 'assets/fonts/xyz.ttf'

Answer (score 0):

I assume you placed your all font in "fonts" folder which is in assets  folder in your project.

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/DIEHLD_.ttf");
                this.setTypeface(tf);